# Importing a DXF into blender, exported from illustrator

Tags: export

I am exporting from Illustrator to a DXF, and when I open this in a DXF viever the lines are ok. Then I imported the DXF in Blender, but I see that many curves are flattened. See the images below.

Illustrator file:

[image: Illustrator file]

Blender import:

[image]

How can I import a DXF into blender, without the curves/lines being flattened?

[DXF and AI file](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/E5inSQ0f32cW4nL8PXL4pA)

Comment: Both images show four curves the sinus shaped tip has been flattened after import. Which curves are you missing? Is the question about the flattening?

Comment: Ah! I did not know this. What is flattening and how can I get the sinus's in my import? So, apparently: yes, this question is about flattening :)

Comment: it would help if you uploaded the dxf file.

Comment: I added a part of the dxf and the ai. I hope that helps! Thanks!